# Is there an easy way to setup a core audio callback to access samples of playing background audio?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, core-audio

How can I access the individual audio samples of playing background music from within my app? Is there a block-based method or callback function that Core Audio provides / calls?

Comment: You should specify how it is that your app is making sound, as that will have a lot to do with how you access the samples (if it is possible at all)

Answer (score 0):

Aha. I did that a lot of times before. Use an API from Stanford. It's called MoMu. It has a C-level API for accessing samples on the left and right channels.